# Black Screen With A buzz after installing ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, vaio

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my Sony Vaio E Series`VPCEHBGG`.

Everything goes right until I take the USB out, and reboot my system.
The Vaio logo shows up, then a black screen with underscore at the top-left of the screen with a buzz sound.

PS: My BIOS does not have a EFI or Legacy choice.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I Finally found the solution, the problem was related to NVIDIA driver,

What I did is:

- started Ubuntu in the test mode (live boot from the USB)
- opened terminal and removed Nouveau:
- `sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`
- Then I installed the NVIDIA Driver using:
- `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331`.

after the installation complete, I reboot the system and it worked!.

PS: I Still have the Buzz sound when I start my computer again

`